# Android how to set and retrieve data from Preference object

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am working on a preference fragment, one preference is to select an external image file as the app background.

I try to save the file path string to the correspond preference, so that I can load that path data from `SharedPreferences` when the app is launched.

My problem is when using `Preference` class instead of `EditTextPreference`, there is no `setText()` method to save the path value, and I cannot figure out how to store the data onto a `Preference` object and then retrieve through `SharedPreferences.getString("key", "")` in my activity.

If I use a `EditTextPreference` instead, indeed it works but I have to disable or customize the dialog component of `EditTextPreference`, since I need to start a new activity to pick a image when tapping this preference.

I notice in the official documentation they use `Preference` when using intent together. Is there any way to save data to a `Preference` object and then retrieve that data in an activity?

```java
// In preference fragment
private Preference bgPref;
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(
      int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
      Uri imageUri = data.getData();
      final String path = getFilePath(requireContext(), imageUri);
      if (path != null) {
        bgPref.setText(path); // how to set a string value for a Preference?
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
        if (containerView != null) {
          containerView.setBackground(d);
        }
      }
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

// In Main activity
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String bgPath = sharedPrefs.getString("bgPath", "");

Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(bgPath);
if (!bgPath.isEmpty()) findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment).setBackground(d);
//...
```

Comment: Have you tried this -> https://github.com/skydoves/PreferenceRoom

Comment: `I cannot figure out how to store the data onto a Preference object and then retrieve through SharedPreferences.getString("key", "") ` ?? You should save your data to shared preferences if you later wanna retrieve it from shared preferences.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I understand your point, indeed it is working with this code in my fragment file, I just wonder if if there is anyway similar with `setText` of `EditTextPreference`. `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
            .edit()
            .putString("bgPath", path)
            .apply();`

Comment: Both, `Preference` and `EditTextPreference` are a UI class, not a way to store data. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference)'s documentation. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) you can read, how to store data in Android.

Comment: If you want the path string to be visible below your Preference, you can simply set your selected path as the summary of that Preference.

Comment: Hi Ananta, sure I tried, as I need to retrieve those data in my activity, and it seems it is not possible to get the summary data through `sharedPrefs.getString("key")`, apparently the summary is not saved as the value of a `Preference` object, so I was looking for another solution. But anyway I use `SharePreferences` in my fragment now, it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this preference directly. In `onActivityResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(
    int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final String path = getFilePath(requireContext(), imageUri);
            if (path != null) {
                // Save preference here
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("bgPath", path);
                editor.apply();
                // Now recreate activity to refresh the UI
                requireActivity().recreate();
                // In onCreateView, you can use this preference to set background
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```